# Column 'user_id' cannot be null when trying to post with Django

Tags: django

I have worked on this error for a while now and I can't figure out what I need to do... This is the error:

```
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
```

What I basically want is to be able to post content to the table blog_blogposts to my database. I'm using Mezzanine.

**views.py:**

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u:u.is_active, login_url='/accounts/login/')
def admin_post_new(request):
    #post = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BlogPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.user = request.user.pk
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('admin_post_list', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = BlogPostForm()
    return render(request, (settings.PROJECT_ROOT + "/main/templates/admin/admin_post_new.html"), {'form': form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
    #
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title', 'content')
```

**admin_post_new.html:**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0;">
  <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should show the full traceback.

Comment: Pretty obvious your `BlogPost` model has `user` attribute which is set to `null=False` or you didn't set it at all (default `null = False`)